# property name 'description' with core data

Tags: sqlite, core-data, properties

I have a SQLite database that I created before using Core Data. I found a site that converts the database so it can be used with Core Data. Everything works great until the program reaches a field name in my model that was called 'description.' In the model, I changed that name to descript. My property, created by Core Data, still have the name description. If I try to change the property to descript, the program crashes, if I leave the property as 'description', it invokes a method in NSObject called description and dumps a whole lot of data from the database into the description field, in my detail view.

I need a work around. How can I change my property to descript so I don't invoke the NSObject method? I don't want to have to redo my whole database. If I comment out that property name in my model object, all the fields show up correctly in my detail table view. But, I can't do without my description field.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you have.  A new app based on Core Data and a converted version of your old database that still has the 'description' attribute ?  If so then you probably do have to change everything to use some other attribute name.  Is this an issue because you have existing data ?  If so you could probably create a mapping model to migrate the data from the old description field to the new 'descrip' field.

Comment: Post the header file of you NSManagedObject subclass. It will be easier to understand what's the problem.